# Editing post author to Subscriber

Tags: wordpress-roles

In WordPress, you are able to edit the author of a post to anyone who has the role of Contributor or higher. I wish to included Subscriber to that list.

I have the plugin "User Role Editor", but I cannot find the correct settings.